# JPA and Hibernate - "persist operation"

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm reading JPA 2.1 specification and there is this fragment:

> A new entity instance becomes both managed and persistent **by invoking
>   the persist method on it or by cascading the persist operation**. The
>   semantics of the persist operation, applied to an entity X are as
>   follows: ...

Is it possible to invoke persist operation without explicitly invoking persist() method or persist operation always have to be a trigger by calling persist() ?

Let's say I have two entities A, and B, where A has `OneToMany(cascade=PERSIST)` relationship with B.

Is

```
tx.begin();
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
a.getBCollection().add(b);
entityManager.persist(a);
tx.commit();
```

the same as:

```
tx.begin();
A a = new A();
entityManager.persist(a);
B b = new B();
a.getBCollection().add(b);
tx.commit();
```

In the second example will the B entity be persisted (persist operation will be cascaded) even if the entity is added after calling persist() method? Or I have to add the B entity to collection before calling persist() method like in first example and only then the persist operation will be cascaded?

And what about #3 example with two transactions:

```
tx1.begin();
A a = new A();
entityManager.persist(a); //persist with key 1L
tx1.commit();

tx2.begin()
B b = new B();
A a = entityManager.find(A.class, 1L);
a.getBCollection().add(b);
tx2.commit();
```

There is no call of persist() method  in second transaction, but A is in managed state, so will the B entity be persisted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [JPA specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html), section **3.2.4** (excerpt):

> The semantics of the flush operation, applied to an entity X are as
>   follows:
>
> - If X is a managed entity, it is synchronized to the database.
>
>   - For all entities Y referenced by a relationship from X, if the relationship to Y has been annotated with the cascade element value
>       cascade=PERSIST or cascade=ALL, the persist operation is applied to Y

So, the answer is yes, `b` is persisted in all your examples by cascading the `PERSIST` operation to it from `a` at flush time.

Comment: so CascadeType.PERSIST is not directly connected to persist() method, MERGE to merge() etc? I alway thought so